# API Яндекс Карты. Как не выполнять событие 'actiontick' если был клик?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карта-api

На сайте реализовано определение координат цента при перетаскивании карты через API Яндекс Карты событие 'actiontick'

```
map.events.add('actiontick', function(e) {
        const tick = e.get('tick');

        const projection = map.options.get('projection').fromGlobalPixels(tick.globalPixelCenter, tick.zoom);

        console.log('Сейчас карта переместится в точку (' +
            map.options.get('projection').fromGlobalPixels(tick.globalPixelCenter, tick.zoom).join(',') +
            ') в течение ' + e.get('tick').duration + ' миллисекунд');

    });
```

Данный код работает как надо, но мне необходимо так же добавить возможность по клике перемещать карту на выбранную точку, данное событие выглядит так:

```
map.events.add('click', function (e) {
            var coords = e.get('coords');
            map.setCenter(coords);
    });
```

При клике по области перемещается карта на нужную точку, все ок. Но при смещении карты срабатывает и 'actiontick' и 'click'.

Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку при клике actiontick срабатывает однократно, первый пришедший в голову "костыль" - счётчик для actiontick, сбрасываемый по клику.

```
var step1
myMap.events.add('actiontick', function (e) {
    const tick = e.get('tick');
    const projection = myMap.options.get('projection').fromGlobalPixels(tick.globalPixelCenter, tick.zoom);
    if (step1 > 0) {
        console.log('Сейчас карта переместится в точку (' +
            myMap.options.get('projection').fromGlobalPixels(tick.globalPixelCenter, tick.zoom).join(',') +
            ') в течение ' + e.get('tick').duration + ' миллисекунд')
    }
    step1++
});

myMap.events.add('click', function (e) {
    step1 = 0
        var coords = e.get('coords');
    myMap.setCenter(coords);
});
```

Пример: https://jsfiddle.net/j7f4qb5m/